# AngularJS: How do I call a function defined in a directive's scope from a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I need to call a function which belongs to the $scope of a ng-directive used in my Angular application.

Let's say the directive is defined like this:

```
.directive('my-directive', ['$document', '$timeout', function ($document, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            // ....
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.myFunction= function (mouseEnter) {
                // ...
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

I need to call **myFunction** from my controller (let's call it **my-controller**) which is the controller of the view where my directive is placed.

Is it possible to do it? (eventually modifying the directive)

**EDIT** : The already answered question provided (proposed for edit) is similar to mine by it's not clear to me or it doesn't apparently solve the specific problem I proposed.

**EDIT 2**: starting from Dan M. answer (without taking mouseenter/mouseleave in consideration. just trying to make the two controllers communicate with each other), I broadcasted my event to my directive's controller through **$rootScope** (as there is there is no parent-child relation between the two controllers) by:

```
console.log("let's broadcast the event.."); // this is printed
$rootScope.$broadcast('callDirectiveControllersFunction'); // I even tried with $scope in place of $rootScope and $emit in place of $broadcast
```

and by receving it (within the directive's controller) by:

```
var myFunction = function(){
   // ...
}

$scope.$on('callDirectiveControllersFunction', function (){
   console.log("event received"); // this is not printed
   callMyFunction(); 
});
// I even tried using $rootScope in place of $scope
```

However in **no case** (see comments in code) the event is received

Comment: I saw that answer before asking. however it's not clear to me and it seems adding some level of complexity to my (simple) issue

Answer (score 1):

You can call a controller function inside the link block. You can also [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) an event in the directive and listen to the it in the controller (maybe there is a use case for that).

It seems that you want to call it on `mouseenter`. You can do that by binding to the `mouseenter` event in the directive link. The catch is you need to $apply the changes. 
Take a look at the following piece of code, which contains all 3 examples: [http://jsbin.com/cuvugu/8/](http://jsbin.com/cuvugu/10/edit). (also pasted below)

Tip: You might want to pay attention to how you name your directives. To use a directive as `my-directive` you need to name it as `myDirective`.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  function directiveLink(scope){
    scope.$emit('customEvent');
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: directiveLink,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.bar = 'bar';
      $scope.myFunction = function () {
        $scope.bar = 'foobar1';
      };

      $scope.$on('customEvent', function (){
        $scope.myFunction();
      });
    },
    template: "Foo {{bar}}"
  };
});

app.directive('anotherDirective', function () {
  function directiveLink(scope){
    scope.myFunction();
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: directiveLink,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.bar = 'bar';
      $scope.myFunction = function () {
        $scope.bar = 'foobar2';
      };
    },
    template: "Foo {{bar}}"
  };
});

app.directive('mouseDirective', function () {
  function directiveLink(scope, element){
    element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.myFunction();
      });
    });

    element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.myOtherFunction();
      });
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: directiveLink,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.bar = 'no';
      $scope.myFunction = function () {
        $scope.bar = 'yes';
      };

      $scope.myOtherFunction = function () {
        $scope.bar = 'no';
      };
    },
    template: "Mouse Enter: {{bar}}"
  };
});
```

I also included an example with a distinct controller in the JS Bin link. That doesn't really change anything, but it seems to be an important part of your question. Here's the code block:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.bar = 'foo';

  $scope.myFunction = function(){
    $scope.bar = 'foobar3';
  };
});

app.directive('lastDirective', function () {
  function directiveLink(scope){
    scope.myFunction();
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: directiveLink,
    controller: 'myController',
    template: "Foo {{bar}}"
  };
});
```

Comment: thank you very much  Dan. the answer is a little bit long and I'm focusing on a different part of the project now. but I'll definitely try your solution in the forthcoming days  and after that I'll accept your answer / ask additional questions

Comment: first of all I apologize for the very late feedback. Please see my "edit 2" in my question.
thank you again

Comment: I finally decided to create a new question. Feel free to answer there if you wish and I'll be glad to accept it if it solves my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884608/calling-a-function-defined-in-a-directives-scope-from-a-controller